# How to add value of selected option in HTML <select> form as variable to its intended action route?

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I'm creating a website that will allow yoga instructors to create classes and allow registered users to signup for them. Everything seems to be working great, but I would like to add functionality to allow an instructor to sign up any user to a class they are instructing (in case the user isn't web-savy but would like to go).

I have the following class models created using Flask SQLAlchemy: User, YogaClass, Signups. Signups is a M2M model that shows establishes the many to many relationship between User and YogaClass (shows which user has signed up for which class). The user model has a `is_instructor` boolean column that, if true, shows the user is an instructor.

On the instructor's home webpage, they can view all the classes they are teaching along with a button allowing them to delete the class.

[image]

I would like to add `<select>` input just to the left of that button that, when clicked, will display all registered users. The instructor would ideally click on a user and then a submit button which would add that user to the class. I am planning to add the user using a Flask route with two variables:

`/classes/instructor_signs_user_up/<int:class_id>/<int:user_id>`

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="container">
  {% if user.classes_teaching %}
    <br><h2 class="lead d-flex justify-content-center">You are scheduled to teach the following classes:</h2><br>
    <div class="row">       
    {% for c in user.classes_teaching %}
      <div class="card col-md-6 col-lg-4 shadow-sm pos-relative">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{c.start_date_time}} - {{c.end_date_time}}</h6>
          <p class="card-text">Location: {{ c.location }}</p>
          <hr>
          {% if c.users %}
            <h5 class="card-text">Who has signed up:</h5>
            <ul>
              {% for u in c.users %}
                {{u.first_name}} {{u.last_name}} <br>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          {% else %}
            <p>Noone signed up yet</p>
          {% endif%}

          <!-- adds a user to a yoga class (instructor only) -->
          <form method="POST" action="/classes/instructor_signs_user_up/{{ c.id }}/{{ INSERT HERE!!! }}">
            <label for="users">Add User to Class:</label>
            <select name="users" id="instructor_adds_user">
              {% for u in all_users %}
                {% if not u.is_instructor %}
                  <option value="{{u.id}}">{{u.first_name}} {{u.last_name}}</option>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Signup">
          </form>

          <form method="POST" action="/classes/instructor_signs_user_up/{{ c.id }}">
            <br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-sm active card-button">Delete Class</button></form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want a user `u` who is an instructor `u.is_instructor = true` to be able to add any user `u` to a specific yoga class `c`. However, I don't know how to insert the selected input value into the action route. I'm sure it is an easy fix, but any suggestions are appreciated. I believe I've provided enough information but can provide more of my code as well.

Here are my class models:

```html
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import pytz
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import delete

bcrypt = Bcrypt()
db = SQLAlchemy()



class Signups(db.Model):
    """Class to establish the many-to-many relationship between the 'users' and 
    'classes' tables. Shows which users have signed up for which classes"""

    __tablename__ = 'signups'

    user_id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    class_id = db.Column('class_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classes.id'), primary_key=True)


class User(db.Model):
    """User in the system."""

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,)
    is_instructor = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, unique=True,)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True,)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False,)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False,)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False,)

    classes_signed_up = db.relationship('YogaClass', secondary='signups', backref='users')
    classes_teaching = db.relationship('YogaClass', backref='instructor')

    @classmethod
    def signup(cls, is_instructor, first_name, last_name, email, password, phone):
        """Sign up user. Hashes password and adds user to system."""

        hashed_pwd = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('UTF-8')

        user = User(
            is_instructor=is_instructor,
            password=hashed_pwd,
            email=email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            phone=phone,
        )

        db.session.add(user)
        return user

    @classmethod
    def authenticate(cls, email, password):
        """Find user with `email` and `password` combination."""

        user = cls.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if user:
            is_auth = bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password)
            if is_auth:
                return user

        #If can't find matching user (or if password is invalid), returns False.
        return False


class YogaClass(db.Model):
    """Yoga Class Model"""

    __tablename__ = 'classes'

    id = db.Column( db.Integer, primary_key=True,)
    instructor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete="cascade"),)
    location = db.Column(db.String,)
    start_date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime,)
    end_date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime,)

    def serialize(self):
        """Serialize classes SQLAlchemy obj to dictionary."""
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "instructor": self.instructor.first_name,
            "location": self.location,
            "start_date_time": self.start_date_time,
            "end_date_time": self.end_date_time,
        }
    

def connect_db(app):
    """Connect this database to Yoga Website."""
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
```

Comment: disregard the route for my delete button! I'm working to fix it